# Disable keyboard shortcuts (was: Leave focus from keyboard)

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, jquery-terminal

Is there a way to leave the terminal from the keyboard?
In an html page, I'm used to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to type an URL, but the only result is a `clear`ing of the console. I'd like to be able to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> directly, but that would be ok with a combination of keys to execute before.

A suggestion BTW, do not call `term.clear()` when `onClear` is defined for a maximum control (like disabling clearing with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable shortcuts using option keydown:

```
.terminal(..., {
    keydown: function(e) {
        if (e.which === 76 && e.ctrlKey) { // CTRL+L
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```